# unable to run ansible playbook to run a bat file

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible

Iam trying to run the ansible playbook to run an bat file in windows local machine.

```
    ---
  - hosts: localhost
    tasks:
        - name: Run command in cmd
          win_shell: sample.bat
```

But i get error `- powershell: not found.`
Please let me know how to install powershell interpreter for ansible.

Comment: `.ps1` is commonly the powershell extension...

Comment: [If you want to run an executable securely and predictably, it may be better to use the win_command module instead](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_shell_module.html)

Answer (score 0):

refer to the docs/examples about using cmd rather than powershell

```
# Run a command under a non-Powershell interpreter (cmd in this case)
- win_shell: C:\path\sample.bat
  args:
    executable: cmd
```

Comment: I tried to use the win shell command but I received below error. "A malformed block was encountered while loading tasks: {u'args': {u'executable': u'cmd'}, u'win_shell': u'C:\..\\sample.bat', u'register': u'homedir_out'} should be a list or None but is <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleMapping'> " Iam just running a vbs file in bat file. Is there any specific format to follow for bat file

Comment: That error is from Ansible not the batch script. This block goes within your tasks